# How to associate checkboxes with other elements in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Consider the following code

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" />

    <style>
      body {
        font-family: "Open Sans";
        font-size: 12px;
      }
    </style>


    <script>
      $( document ).ready(function()
      {

      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="py-5 text-center">
        <img class="d-block mx-auto mb-4" alt="" width="72" height="72">

        <p class="lead">Search</p>
      </div>
      <form class="needs-validation form-horizontal" action="search.php" onsubmit="$(this).find('input').prop('disabled', false)" method="post">
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-3">
            <h5>Strains</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class='form-row'>
          <div class=' col-md-3 mb-3'>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input' id='strainName_chkboxID' name='strainName_chkbox_htmlName'>
              <label class='custom-control-label' for='strainName_chkboxID'>strain name</label>
                      <input type='text' id='strain_nameID' class='form-control' name='strainName_htmlName' required title='strain name'>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input' id='isolationName_chkboxID' name='isolationName_chkbox_htmlName'>
              <label class='custom-control-label' for='isolationName_chkboxID'>isolation name</label>
                      <input type='text' id='isolationNameID' class='form-control' name='isolationName_htmlName' required title='isolation name'>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input' id='dateFrozen_chkboxID' name='dateFrozen_chkbox_htmlName'>
              <label class='custom-control-label' for='dateFrozen_chkboxID'>date frozen</label>
                      <input type='date' id='dateFrozenID' class='form-control' name='dateFrozen_htmlName' required title='date frozen'>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input' id='dateThawed_chkboxID' name='dateThawed_chkbox_htmlName'>
              <label class='custom-control-label' for='dateThawed_chkboxID'>date thawed</label>
                      <input type='date' id='dateThawedID' class'form-control' name='dateThawed_htmlName' required title='date thawed'>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Questions

1) Why is the font size of the checkboxes correct (per the body tag), but the edit fields are ignoring that and displaying at a larger size?

2) The last field, date thawed, however, displays at the right size. Why?

3) Why with container-fluid, does everything align off the edge of the window, and how can I fix that without changing to plain container?

4) When displayed on my server, each form groups shows up one below the other even though they are assigned to a single row? How can I get them to appear side by side? The form-horizontal tag seems to be being ignored.

Comment: I got it to display across 4 columns by supplying a column div for each form group, but this causes the checkboxes to overlap with the edit fields. How to fix?

Comment: You can see the code in action at https://jsfiddle.net/mauricev/uty7vp1n/7/. This has been updated to show the overlapping problem with the "oversized" edit fields, except for the last one.

Comment: The wrong sized item is due to "class'form-control", which should be "class='form-control".

Comment: I found out there is a way to tie checkboxes to input using input-addon tags, but what I'm trying to do here is still required where a label is needed. For example, for the date fields.

Comment: The last field, which you claim displays at the right size, is invalid, because of `class'form-control'` (which should be `class='form-control'`). Because of this, class `form-control` is not being applied. What do you mean by *"displays at the right size"*?

Comment: I figured that out as you can see from my second comment. The right size comment was actually referring to the one where the correct size was NOT being applied. Anyway, I'm still interested to know if there's a way to get the checkboxes to no overlap the text fields.